# How to build a Quarry of a size larger than 64x64 in Feed the Beast?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Please explain with screenshots how to do this and how and in which order and where I have to place and activate the quarry and the landmarks.
I have read that this is possible, but I fail at replicating this.

Comment: Does your modpack contain Quarry+? Because only Quarry+ can go bigger then 64x64 AFAIK

Comment: Oh good to know. I read it here: http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Quarry and I'm using ftb unleashed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Buildcraft quarry doesn't support areas larger than 64x64.
Quarry+ adds a block called Quarry+ which can support up to 256x256.

If you have Extra-utilities installed then use the Ender Quarry, it can support an unlimited* (read stupidly large) area.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to build a quarry larger than 64x64, which is stated on the [wiki](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Quarry):

> By default, it (the [Quarry](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Quarry)) will mine out a 9x9 area with a frame of 11x11. However, this can be extended to a **max** of 62x62 mining area with a frame of 64x64.

I would recommend placing a number of quarries adjacent to each other and connecting them together with pipes.

Answer (score 1):

for those who still want to create a quarry that is bigger then 64x64 in 1.12.2 and up, it is still possible, although the method mentioned by erhannis no longer works.
heres how:

1. place landmarks as though you are making a usual 64x64 quarry:
   [image]
2. break the landmark which is connected to 2 other landmarks(IT IS IMPORTANT THAT THE LANDMARK YOU BREAK MUST BE CONNECTED TO 2 OTHER LANDMARKS!!!) so it looks like this:
   [image]
3. Place a 3rd landmark like so:
   [image]
4. when you right click it, the laser should extend beyond 64x64 to whatever size you desired, like so:
   [image]
5. break the middle landmark, and repeat as many as you like
   [image]
6. for the other direction, repeat step 3 to 5
   [image]

Thats it, do keep in mind that the quarry block needs a land mark behind it in order to be placed, and this method "inverts" the position of the landmarks, so keep in mind the positioning of your quarry.

also larger superquarrys goes through each layer much slower then a smaller one, resulting in more cobble and other stuff to deal with.

proof that it works with my 128x128 superquarry made using this method(if you look closly, there should be a landmark that is turned on, but the laser does not reach all the way to the end[image]

update: i noticed that on massive superquarryes, there can be loading issues, which can cause the quarry to dig unevenly as a result. To solve it simply break one if the frame to"reboot" and it will mine out the uneven areas

[image]

Comment: One more thing, still increase forgeChunkLoading.cfg's I:maximumChunksPerTicket value to be extra sure nothing weird happens

Answer (score 0):

You can't. What you can do is put down multiple quarries, however.

Answer (score 0):

Guess what?  You CAN use the quarry for greater than 64x64 areas!  It's not a limitation of the quarry, but rather that it's difficult to get landmarks to form an area like that, as they can only connect to other landmarks up to a certain distance away (63 or 64, depending on how you count it, I think).  (I will grant that perhaps it has become possible in the time since the other answers were posted, but evidence faintly suggests otherwise.)  After a great deal of experimentation and looking at source code, I've figured out how to get, for instance, a ~192x192 landmarked area, which the quarry can use.

Note, before we begin, that as mentioned on http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Quarry, which I think you've read, the quarry is limited by forgeChunkLoading.cfg's `I:maximumChunksPerTicket` value, so edit config/forgeChunkLoading.cfg and change all instances of `I:maximumChunksPerTicket` to be suitably high; probably several hundred.  I picked 256.

Note also that I'm using Minecraft 1.7.10, with the relevant Forge 10.13.4.1517, and BuildCraft 7.1.9.

Here's the basic process.  I'm doing it here with the landmarks having only a single space between them, but it also worked (for me, several times) with the landmarks at max distance.  Just scale it up as desired.  Remember to place redstone torches next to your landmarks to see what the max distance is to their next neighbor.

1. Place landmark A in the NE corner.  Place landmark B south of A, and landmark C east of A.  Right-click on landmark A.  You should see lasers making a square with corners B, A, and C.
   [image: Place three torches in the NE corner]
   [image: Right-click the NE one]
2. Place landmark D east of C.  Right-click it.  Don't worry that it looks like you have more than one marked area.
   [image: Add another landmark to the east]
   [image: Right-click it]
3. Do it again (landmark E), if you like, probably as many times as you want (and your computer will support).
   [image: Another landmark to the east]
   [image: Right-click it]
4. Place landmark F south of B.  Right-click it.  It effectively extends the area south.
   [image: Add another landmark to the south]
   [image: Right-click it]
5. Do it again (landmark G), if you like, probably as many times as you want (and your computer will support).
   [image: Another landmark to the south]
   [image: Right-click it]
6. Place quarry.  It may matter where you do this - try to place it near the last landmark you activate; that should work.  (There may be other smaller marked areas created by this process; you don't want to accidentally use one of them for your quarry.)
   [image: Place quarry]

Also, it MAY matter which orientation you do this in - N/E/S/W; I recommend doing it the orientation I've written, if possible.

Here's some pictures of it on the 192x192 scale, on a flatland I made in MCEdit.  Each checker-tile is a chunk, and I've colored each 4x4 square of chunks in alternating colors to mark approx how big a quarry can usually be.
[image: Quarry destroying stuff]
Here it is starting to mine:
[image: Quarry starting to mine]
Here's the quarry (in a different spot; different test run), text saying it'll keep 145 chunks loaded:  (Still 3x3 max-areas, btw.)
[image: Quarry will keep 145 chunks loaded]
After increasing my maximumChunksPerTicket, I set up a 6x7 max-area quarry, which loaded 672 chunks.  (Got one of the dimensions wrong, somehow, or it'd be a 7x7.)  At that scale, it was visually a little glitchy, like lasers disappearing as you reached the farther landmarks, or the digging-arm being invisible.  I suspect it's something to do with a maximum visual length of such objects, or possibly something to do with chunk-loading, though that makes less sense once the quarry's in place.  Either way, it works fine.  I did run around the perimeter once before placing the quarry, to make sure the chunks loaded once more before I put down the quarry.  Dunno if that's necessary.
[image: 672 chunks loaded]

That should do it!  Hereafter follows a brief explanation of why I think it exhibits this behavior.

This is all related to how landmarks keep track of the area they mark: they each store a variable for the dimensions of the box that encompasses them.  They try to keep it in sync with the other landmarks in the structure, but I'm not convinced it's quite right - I think that's part of why you end up with odd sub-areas.  As you add landmarks to the edges of the structure, it inherits the origin and dimensions of the box, expanding the box to include its(landmark)self.

Side note, each landmark has 3 variables, one each for their neighbors on the X, Y, and Z axis, respectively.  When checking for neighbors (when you right-click on it) it checks in the following order: +x -x +y -y +z -z.  Honestly, though, the behavior of the landmarks still looks a little erratic to me, and not fully in line with what I expected, given the code.

Comment: BTW, upon inspection, I've discovered that my 6x7 max-area quarry had another landmark unused past the end of its 6 axis.  I don't know if that's because I forgot to activate it, or if it's evidence of a flaw in my process.